# Using javascript, is it possible to pull and list all available languages through Google Translate?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-translate

I'm tinkering with a site that has a sort of module/extension that lets you turn a translator bar on/off. It appears on every page like a persistent notification bar, and lists languages you can pick. Right now, the translator.js file being used has an array that lists available languages by using the Google Language codes: https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#language-params

Instead of manually coding in the language codes to be used, is there a way to just get them all from Google and then put them into an array?

Comment: You can do a GET and grab the supported languages, see: https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest#supported-languages

Answer (score 0):

GET https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/languages?key=YOUR_KEY&target=LANGUAGE_FOR_NAMES

```
{
    "data": {
        "languages": [
            {
                "language": "af",
                "name": "Afrikaans"
            },
            {
                "language": "sq",
                "name": "Albanian"
            },

           ...

            {
                "language": "yo",
                "name": "Yoruba"
            },
            {
                "language": "zu",
                "name": "Zulu"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```